# Zend Framework URL to action in specifiic module

Tags: php, url, zend-framework, module

I have 2 modules: "Mobilewebapp" and "Backoffice". My default module is "Mobilewebapp".
I have a layout "backoffice.phtml" for my backoffice. In there I have the following:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'logout'), null, true) ?>">Logout</a>
```

The problem is that the links always goes to the default module "mobilewebapp". I already tried this but still the same:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('module' => 'backoffice', 'controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'logout'), null, true) ?>">Logout</a>
```

My application.ini:

> [production]
>   phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
>   phpSettings.display_errors = 1
>   includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
>   bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
>   bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
>   appnamespace = "Application"
>   resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
>   resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
>   resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
>
> resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH
>   "/modules" resource.modules[] = ""
>   resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1"
>   resources.frontController.defaultModule = "mobilewebapp"
>
> [staging : production]
>
> [testing : production] phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
>   phpSettings.display_errors = 1
>
> [development : production] phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
>   phpSettings.display_errors = 1
>   resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

Comment: Show me the config.ini

Comment: http://blog.ericlamb.net/2010/04/zend-framework-url-view-helper/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this

> url(array('module' => 'backoffice',
>   'controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'logout')) ?>">Logout